# bindFormRequest() encounter a cannot find symbol error in Play 2.0.3

Tags: java, forms, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

I create a form with Play framework. but I get a `error: cannot find symbol` 
I reviewed the example codes in play directory, still can not figure it out. by the way, can I use Play to access PostgresSQL in heroku? 
This is following code:

This is piece of code in /controllers/Application.java

```
    final static Form<Geo> geoForm = form(Geo.class);

    public static Result showDBpage(){

          //get problem here :-<
          Form<Geo> filledForm = geoForm.bindFormRequest(); 
          Geo loc = filledForm.get();
          return ok(database.render(loc));
        }
```

This is conf/routes:

```
POST    /database   controllers.Application.showDBpage()
```

views/database.scala.html

```
@(loc: Geo)

@main("") {

    <p>This is Database pages</p>

    <p>@loc.longitute and @loc.latitute</p>

    <a href=@routes.Application.index>Back to form</a>
}
```

models/Geo.java:

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.validation.*;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.*;

public class Geo
  {
    @Required
    public String longitute;
    @Required
    public String latitute;

    public Geo()
    {

    }

    public Geo(String longitude,String latitute)
    {
        this.longitute = longitute;
        this.latitute = latitute;
        //this.length = length;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

There is NO method <s>bindFormRequest()</s> but `bindFromRequest()` - you have a typo in your code.

Check the API http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/java/play/data/Form.html

Comment: thanks dude, what a stupid question. It took me a few hours on Google.

Comment: @Ryan There're no stupid questions ;) It took me a while to realize your typo as well. Anyway I'd recommend to invest in some good IDE - it allows to catch such annoying bugs in seconds, not hours. Mark the question as answered.

Comment: Thanks @biesior, I will try eclipse soon

Comment: Also try the Intellij Idea (Ultimate) it's better than Eclipse for Play, IMHO.